# Can we add Tasklet and Chunks inside a JOB together?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch, scheduled-tasks

I have added Tasklet Steps and Chunk based Steps together inside job ,But my job is only running the Tasklet Steps not the Chunk Steps.

I have added Tasklet because i have to upload csv file generated in my previous steps into Salesforce.As taklet don't accept any reader/writer/processor. So i am calling the Salesforce Upload process inside tasket.

Below code :`@Bean
public Job job() throws Exception {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("job").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())

```
            .start(deleteRecordsFromTableStep())
            .next(step1())
            .next(step2())
            .next(slfLeadsDataUploadStep())
            .next(step3())
            .next(step4())
            .next(step5())
            .next(slfActivityDataUploadStep())
            .next(step6())
            .build();
}`
```

Taklet Part:`
    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public Step deleteRecordsFromTableStep() {
return stepBuilderFactory.get("deleteRecordsFromTableStep").tasklet(tableDeletingTasklet()).build();
    }

```
@Bean
@Lazy
public DeleteTableTasklet tableDeletingTasklet() {
    return new DeleteTableTasklet();
}`
```

Comment: It's definitely possible to use both types of steps in a single job. You should have a job configuration or flow definition issue, please share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the problem to be able to help you.

Comment: Thank You  Mahmoud Ben Hassine. I have a method written in constructor .That is only called at the time when Application Starts.It is not getting called in scheduled time interval, that i am using @Scheduled for scheduling with corn expression. Do we have any such mechanism where we can restart our application in a scheduled interval ??